# Scale aware adaptive camera zooming

Tags: camera

I would like to implement an interactive zoom on a 3d object with mouse wheel.A naive approach is simple where you just scale camera marix Z poistion or modify FOV.But I would like the zoom scaling to be aware to the scale of the object and adapt its speed to it accordingly.It is standard behavior of [CAD programs](http://apps.123dapp.com/design/) like Maya and 3d max.In [this demo](http://baicoianu.com/~bai/three.js/examples/webgl_camera_logarithmicdepthbuffer.html)  the zoom scaling is performed by exponential grow of the value but it would still be the same for models with radius of 10 units and 100000 units.I am sure eventually I will probably roll my own solution but I am interested to know if there are some industry standard techniques for this kind of interactivity.

Also I am sorry if this is not an appropriate place to ask.I thought game devs should have some experience in this area.

Comment: If you want to scale the speed of the camera by the size of the object, why not... do that? What exactly are you stuck with?

Comment: I am not stuck.I want to know if there is a already " a right way" of doing it,so not to reinvent the wheel.